# Não consigo linkar para css com caminho relativo

Tags: php, html, css

Estou usando Valet e o meu link para o arquivo css não está funcionando. Tenho isso no meu arquivo `/exemplo/index.php`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

O arquivo está em `/exemplo/css/style.css`. O browser tenta carregar o arquivo `/css/style.css`.

Acabei de fazer mais um teste aqui e reparei que quando acesso `http://local.dev/example` não funciona. Mas quando acesso `http://local.dev/example/index.php` funciona.

Até que faz sentido isso, mas existe alguma forma de fazer funcionar nos dois? Nem que seja uma função do php.

Comment: Simples. `href="exemple/css/style.css"`

Comment: @GiovaniRodrigo Não é bem assim. Primeiro porque o certo seria `href="exemple/css/style.css"`. Segundo porque não sei o nome da pasta. São várias pastas. Como eu disse, preciso que o caminho seja relativo.

Comment: O caminho onde o PHP se encontra é irrelevante. O que importa é o URL usado para acessar a página. Seria bom [edit] a pergunta e acrescentar esta informação. (isto tudo supondo que a base não seja mudada no HTML, o que seria um problema extra)

Comment: @Bacco Acabei de editar com mais informações. Para ficar mais claro, o meu sistema cria pastas com um template que tem um `index.php` e um `css/style.css`. E preciso que funcione em todas as páginas.

Comment: tem certeza que o example/ do que não funciona foi testado com a barra no final? Se usa PHP, não seria o caso de usar caminho partindo da raiz? Dificil um caso real em que a pessoa precise de relativo mesmo. O relativo faz um pouco mais de sentido em código que terceiros vão utilizar, e podem estar em níveis diferentes dependendo da situação de cada um.

Comment: Acabei de verificar, com a barra no final funciona, sem a barra não funciona.

Comment: Melhor seria consertar isso então. O ideal é que seja sempre acessado por um URL único. Por exemplo, forçando a barra sempre. Ou nunca usando a barra. Ter URL "variando" é ruim para indexação, e outras coisas mais (como você acaba de notar). Ou usa sem barra e inclui o example no caminho, ou usa com barra e parte do css/

Comment: Não que você não possa ajustar pelo PHP, mas se é para fazer isso, já faça absoluto (relativo à raiz, na verdade) sempre. Eu ainda acho que simplifica padronizar a barra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caminho relativo é um problema no cenário descrito. Os 2 URLs mencionados estão de fato em caminhos diferentes, esse "relativo" seria a qual?

```
http://local.dev/example
http://local.dev/example/index
```

Neste caso o relativo à raiz é menos problemático (chamado de absoluto, mas acredito não ser a melhor terminologia, pois não inclui o domínio).

Uma alternativa, se precisar "relativizar" mesmo, é forçar o script a ter sempre uma barra ao final (ou nunca, fazendo o respectivo ajuste no caminho do CSS).

Algo assim:

```
<?php
    $caminho = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if( substr( $caminho, -1 ) !== '/' && substr( $caminho, -4 ) !== '.php' ) {
        header( 'Location: '.$caminho.'/' );
        die();
    }
```

Se precisar usar *query string* pode acrescentar no `header` também, concatenando depois da barra com uma `?`.

Dependendo do servidor e configuração, pode ser o caso de trocar o `PHP_SELF` por `PATH_INFO`.